# Batched BM25 search in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, sentence-similarity

I have a large dataset of documents (average length of 35 words). I want to find the top `k` nearest neighbors of all these documents by using BM25. Every document needs to be compared with every other document in this dataset and the top `k` neighbors have to be populated. I need this to be parallelised because the dataset size ranges to about 40M.

I tried using multiprocessing but the compute of a server is the bottleneck since it cannot scale into multiple nodes like pyspark can.

I'm using this code to do this but it gets stuck indefinitely when I try to show the df

```
import math
from collections import Counter

def calculate_bm(row, documents):
    row_dict = row.asDict()
    query = row_dict["sentence"]
    documents = documents
    document_count = len(documents)
    avg_document_length = sum(len(doc) for doc in documents) / document_count
    
    term_counts = Counter()
    for document in documents:
        term_counts.update(document)

    k1 = 1.2
    b = 0.75

    document_scores = []
    for document in documents:
        score = 0.0
        document_length = len(document)
        query_terms = Counter(query)

        for term in query_terms:
            if term not in documents:
                continue
            
            document_with_term_count = term_counts[term]
            idf = math.log((document_count - document_with_term_count + 0.5) / (document_with_term_count + 0.5))
    
            term_frequency = document.count(term)
            numerator = term_frequency * (k1 + 1)
            denominator = term_frequency + k1 * (1 - b + b * (document_length / avg_document_length))
            score += idf * (numerator / denominator)

        document_scores.append((document, score))
    
    ranked_documents = sorted(document_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    
    for idx, entry in enumerate(ranked_documents):
        row_dict[f"NN_{idx}"] = entry[0]
        row_dict[f"D_{idx}"] = entry[1]
    
    newrow = Row(**row_dict)
    return newrow

all_documents = temp_df.select(F.collect_list('sentence')).first()[0]

dist = df.rdd.map(lambda row: calculate_bm(row, all_documents))
dist_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dist)
```

My df looks like this (40M rows, ~60 columns)

```
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
| idx |                     sentence                      |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1  | [column 1 name, value, column 2 name, value, ...] |
|  2  | [column 1 name, value, column 2 name, value, ...] |
|  3  | [column 1 name, value, column 2 name, value, ...] |
|  4  | [column 1 name, value, column 2 name, value, ...] |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The output is wish is this:

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| idx |  neighbours  |    distances   |
+--------------------+----------------+
|  1  | [2,4,61,...] | [0.01,0.02,...]|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

I was able to find this [implementation](https://github.com/yu-iskw/spark-ranking-algorithms/blob/master/docs/okapi-bm25.md) but it's in scala and sadly I'm not able to translate it to pyspark.

Comment: Do you really need to re-implement the Scala code in Python? Wouldn't it be easier to use the Scala library in PySpark?

Comment: How long does it takes on your hardware to compute BM25s of just one sentence vs 10M remaining ones? Also: are these 40M entries of your input unique?

Comment: @darked89 It takes 3s for 1 sentence
All 40M of these are unique upto 40% of their length i.e., there's atleast a 60% overlap of terms(words) among documents

Comment: I would look into `polars` python library. Load 40M sentences in one column, add idx, split the sentences into a list, sort the lists.  In `[column 1 name, value,`: `col1name` == `some_word` and `value`  == `frequency_of_some_word_in_sentence_1`?

Comment: `score` is a float in python. It uses 24bytes. So to store 40M floats you would need 960MB of RAM. Actually more, since you must store pairs `idx`:`score` . This means: you may need to compare each computed score to top `k` stored scores updating that dictionary.  Did you checked how much RAM is being used simply loading the 40M 35 words data set?

Comment: @darked89 The issue with pandas (or polars) is that they're limited to the resources on the machine. Frameworks like pyspark can scale to multiple nodes on demand and then scale down. This is helpful since I wish to compute the above quickly, allowing a intermittent spike in the number of nodes (resources) but cannot afford a script running for hours

Comment: I did not suggest that `polars` is a solution to all the steps. My idea was to experiment on a single, possibly local machine with hopefully more efficient data models and check the performance on a subsets. For that multithreded `polars` tends to be way faster than `pandas` or `pyspark` not to mention iterating over dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, just few suggestions:

1. split your `calculate_bm` function

Things like number of tokens in a sentence or frequency counts of tokens in the whole data sets imho should be out an not bundled with most problematic /CPU intense BM25

2. tokens as integers
   No idea if you have it done already, but your `df`:

```
|  1  | [column 1 name, value, column 2 name, value, ...] |
```

is a bit cryptic for me. Since it is not `[token_a, token_b, ...]` it must be mixing up different data types.

instead of just giving tokens sequential numbers one can collect all the tokens from a set of sentences (`documents` in your code?), compute the frequencies in the whole data set, then sort in the descending order getting overall token frequency data frame:

```
┌──────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ token_id ┆ tokens ┆ count │
│ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ u32      ┆ str    ┆ u32   │
╞══════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0        ┆ the    ┆ 3193  │
│ 1        ┆ of     ┆ 1850  │
│ 2        ┆ and    ┆ 1317  │
│ 3        ┆ in     ┆ 1304  │
│ …        ┆ …      ┆ …     │
│ 6        ┆ et     ┆ 581   │
```

Then the original string tokens can be translated to `token_id` and sorted producing:

```
┌─────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ sentence_nr ┆ tokens           │
│ ---         ┆ ---              │
│ u32         ┆ list[u32]        │
╞═════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 0           ┆ [0, 1, … 524]    │
│ 1           ┆ [0, 0, … 3132]   │
│ 2           ┆ [0, 1, … 4701]   │
│ 3           ┆ [0, 9, … 5150]   │
```

Less RAM used, faster look-ups compared to strings.

3. save the intermediate data frames

If possible I would try to use 'parquet' format readable by 'spark' etc.

That way you can skip steps already done/verify that these make sense.

Hope it helps a bit.